# Выдает ошибку "Trying to get property of non-object" при проверке Auth::user() на соответствие

Tags: php, laravel

Код

```
@if(Auth::user()->id_UsGr == 1)
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Админка</a>
</li>
@endif
```

Здесь @if(Auth::user()->id_UsGr == 1) проверяет если у вошедшего юзера id_UsGr = 1 то выводит список.

При разлогине выдает ошибку "Trying to get property of non-object" при проверке Auth::user() на соответствие.

Не понимаю что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать без уточнений по фреймоврку или хотя бы описания алгоритма авторизации, но скорее всего дело обстоит так - пользователь уже не залогинен и поэтому `Auth::user()` отдает `null`, property `id_UsGr` которого вы пытаетесь получить, но это уже не объект. Так и расшифровывается ошибка

> Trying to get property of non-object